# Laravel websockets en channel private

Tags: laravel, vue.js, websocket

Hola chicos saben estoy implementando laravel websockets para una aplicación con vuejs pero son 2 proyectos separados, es decir no implemento vuejs en laravel.
Mi configuración es la siguiente:

Broadcasting.php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien tengo habiliatado este provider

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en mi proyecto en vuejs tambien tengo configurado esto segun la documentación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que pasa el lo siguiente, los canales publicos si me funcionan el problema esta cuando quiero usar un canal privado entonces me vota el siguiente error:

localhost:8080/broadcasting/auth ---> 404

Ahora analizando esto tiene razón por que como coloco en mi frotend la escucha del canal privado, esta tomado el host de mi frotend que viene hacer 'localhost:8080' cuando deberia tomar 'localhost:8000' que es el de mi backend y es ahí donde se tiene que authenticar.
Yo decidí ponerlo manual algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el problema es que me sale cosas de CORS así que revisando en otros foros me dice que lo
coloque así habilitando el enabledTransports: ['ws']:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esta ultima modificación ya no me sale ningún error pero el problema esta
porque al parecer el canal ya no esta ala escucha y no me votan ningún resultado.

Me gustaría por favor que me ayuden con esto haber si estoy haciendo algo mal.

Comment: Te recomiendo que no uses imágenes de código. Puedes editar tu pregunta, copiar y pegarlo. Eso simplifica las cosas a la hora de revisarlo y darte una respuesta.

Comment: Pudiste encontrar la solución?